# jQuery How to test if this <a> has href attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Very simple question...

for

`$('a')`

How do I test if that jQuery object has an HREF attribute? I'm Looking for something that will return true or false that I can use in an if() statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you wish to check for elements with empty href attributes as well, or just elements that has no href attribute specified at all, which would of course be invalid HTML.

Comment: I want to check for elements with *no* href attribute. in HTML5 the href is not required

Comment: Yes, but that would make it a placeholder, and they can be targeted differently, see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J6rCF/)...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jQuery's .attr() function will return undefined if the attribute to be found is missing in the selected element(s).

```
if($('a').attr('href') === undefined) { 
   // Element 'a' has no href
}
```

Note: There are other ways to test for `undefined`.

Comment: is this better?

if(typeof $this.attr('href') === "undefined")

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, but it works as well. EDIT: Wait, its `if(typeof $(this).attr('href') === "undefined")`

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('a').not($('a:link')).length) {
    //you have `<a>` elements that are placeholders only
}
```

Comment: just this method worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
if((typeof $('a').attr('href')) !== 'undefined') { 
  // a has attr href, with 'undefined' not undefined 
}
```

tried with jquery 1.8 on chrome, firefox, safari and ie8.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(!$('a').attr('href')) {      
     alert("<a> does not have href attribute");    
}
```

This code also checks for empty links. Note: Jquery attribute values are strings.

http://jsfiddle.net/TzUN3/204/